# Rails 4 - Update table by links from collection with AJAX UJS

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, ujs

I have a list of news from a collection.

Above is a pagination list with year numbers, 2010 -> 2014

Clicking on each will sort the list of news by that year.

I want to AJAXify it, so no page reloading would occur.

What am I missing?

An index.js.erb file with some UJS, but how should that be done?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

**news_controller.rb:**

```
@news_years = News.all.map { |news| news.date.year }.uniq.sort

if params[:year].present?
  @news = News.order("date DESC").by_year(params[:year].to_i).load
else
  @news = News.order("date DESC").by_year(DateTime.now.year).load
end

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @news }
  format.js
end
```

**index.haml:**

```
%ul.pagination
  - @news_years.each do |year|
    - if params[:year] == year.to_s
      %li.active
        %span.page
          = link_to year, news_index_path(:year => year.to_s), remote: true
    - else
      %li
        %span.page
          = link_to year, news_index_path(:year => year.to_s), remote: true

.panel-group#news-accordion
  - cache(cache_key_for_news) do
    - @news.each do |news|
      = render partial: 'news', locals: {news: news}
```

**_news.haml:**

```
- cache(news) do
  .panel.panel-default
    .panel-heading.panel-heading-custom
      .panel-title
        %a{:"data-toggle" => "collapse", :"data-parent" => "#news-accordion", :href => "#collapse-#{news.id}"}
          %i.fa.fa-plus.fa-1x
          %small= news.date.strftime('%d.%m.%y') unless news.date.blank?
          \-
          %small= news.title
          - if can? :manage, news
            = link_to t('.edit_news'), edit_news_path(news), class: 'btn btn-primary btn-xs', role: 'button'
            = link_to t('.delete_news'), news, :confirm => 'Er du sikker?', :method => :delete, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-xs', role: 'button'

     .panel-collapse.collapse{:id => "collapse-#{news.id}"}
       .panel-body
         = news.content.html_safe
         %br/
```

Answer (score 0):

index.js.erb must fill the #news-accordion block. it should be something like:

```
$("#news-accordion").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'all_news', news: @news) %>");
```

and the partial _all_news.html.erb

```
news.each do |news|
  = render partial: 'news', locals: {news: news}
```

Optionally, in index.html I would render _all_news.html.erb instead of looping each news.